# Generate custom amount of combobox options

Tags: javascript, combobox

I need to create a combobox generator that generates as many "options" as there are database columns
for example if there are 10 columns with user names it would show 10 options to me.
If there were 5 columns in my database it would show 5 options in my combobox.

```
<div style="float:right;" class="combox">
     <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      </select>
       </div>
```

Javascript

```
    var options = 6,
    for(var i = 0; i < options; i++) {
        $('1').append('<option></option>');
            $('table').find('option').eq(i).append('<option></option>');
           ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or paste some of your efforts you have done so far

Comment: @Curiousdev updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find my snippet below give a class to `Select` element and than append all option like below

```js
var options = 6;
    for(var i = 1; i < options + 1; i++) {
        
      $('.clsselect').append('<option>'+i+'</option>');
            
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="combox">
     <select class="clsselect">
      </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Ohh that's great you are always welcome gald it help you cheers :)